# Field's default value by TypoScript in TYPO3 Powermail extension

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Does anybody know whether it is possible to set the default value of any field of Powermail form with TypoScript (without creating a special TypoScript object field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting value of hidden field is built-in in powermail, of course it works only with `fe_users` table.

When editing field you'll find it at the bottom of the properties: `Fill out this field with fe_user field`

If you need to use other fields from DB, you can configure them via ExtensionManager.

**Edit:**

There is mentioned in docs that's possible to prefill values with TS, I didn't test in, however looks, that's what are you need.

http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/1.4.14/view/1/10/#id1632010

Comment: Thanks, but I need TypoScript processing of the data, so the question is how to do it with TypoScript, to put any TSObject as default value of the field.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. Use the TCAdefaults typoscript object in your **page [ts config](http://wiki.typo3.org/TSconfig)**.

```
TCAdefaults.tt_news.hidden = 0
```

This example makes tt_news entries not hidden. The format is

```
TCAdefaults.[table].[field] = [value]
```

and this works with everything that is inside a tca. So you can practically set defaults for any field in any table.

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about Powermail form !

Comment: Following the [documentation](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/powermail/1.4.15/view/1/4/), you can set that in the backend directly. What exactly is your use case?

Comment: For example, to fill a hidden field with Id, name, and email of FE user.